# Selective load using AVX2 C++

Tags: c++, avx2

I am trying to achieve the following using AVX2 but not been able to do after spending half a day. 
I tried using maskload and other things, but havent been able to solve the problem.

I have two double precision arrays, a and b.

```
double a[] = {-1000.00, 0.00, 2000.00, 3500.00};
double b[] = {1.25, 1.636, -2.50, 3.25};
```

I want to load only those values from `b` into a `__m256d` for which corresponding value in `a` are non zero, otherwise it is set to 0.

Something like:

```
double c[4];
for(int i=0; i<4; ++i)
{
    if a[i] == 0
        c[i] = 0;
    else
        c[i] = b[i];
}
```

Can someone help?

Edit: This is a part of a larger problem, does not have only 4 values hence I dont want to calculate another array like I have here and the load that array into registers.

Comment: Is loading the discarded entries from `b` allowed, or must they be untouched?

Comment: yes we can load it into a temporary variable and then get rid of them later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the entries of `b` can be loaded unconditionally, the entries that should be zeroed out can be zeroed with a mask:

```
__m256d zero = _mm256_setzero_pd();
__m256d c = _mm256_and_pd(b, _mm256_cmp_pd(zero, a, _CMP_NEQ_UQ));
```

Using `_CMP_NEQ_UQ` means that a NaN in `a` does not zero the entry, while with `_CMP_NEQ_OQ` both zero and NaN would zero out the entry.

Comment: On Skylake, `_mm256_maskload_pd` should be just as efficient, with the same `vcmppd` result as the mask.  Although it might have worse latency if the mask has to be ready before the load can start.  `vmaskmovpd` as a load is 2 fused-domain uops, p23 + p015 on Skylake.  It's also efficient on Ryzen, only a single uop (per 128 bits).  But on Broadwell or earlier it's 3 uops, p23 + 2p5 which is terrible vs. `vandpd`.